# How to get number as key in React hook form names

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a scenario where i need to take input with number as key of an object

(expected output)

```
count: {
  1: "value",
  2: "value"
}
```

using react hook form naming convention, i gave

```
<input type="text" name={"count.5"} ref={register} />
```

when i take values, I'm getting an array instead of an object.

```
{count: Array(6)}

 > count: Array(6)

0: undefined

1: undefined

2: undefined

3: undefined

4: undefined

5: "1"
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-kalam-q0wwu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: this is a known issue. look here: https://spectrum.chat/react-hook-form/help/problem-with-numeric-keys-in-object~28745526-3301-4871-81a5-d8eeffa9f410

Comment: well, I'm using a workaround by setting writing <space>5 and later on trimming it. It works like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its a known issue and author has suggested a workaround.

I came up with a solution to add space or some character before the number.

```
<input type="text" name={"count. 5"} ref={register} />

<input type="text" name={"count.x5"} ref={register} />
```

and use the same pattern for setting the fields ( if you're using setValue or defaultValue from hook form)

when using the key value, trimming the added char will be required.